# Pandas - assign histogram bucket to each row

Tags: python, performance, pandas, histogram, vectorization

Here is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3, 2, 7]})
buckets = [(0,3),(3,5),(5,9)]
```

I also have histogram buckets stated above. Now I would like to assign each row of dataframe to buckets index. So I would like to get new column with the following info:

```
df['buckets_index']  = [0,0,0,1,2,1,0,0,2]
```

Of course, I can do it with loops, but I have fairly big dataframe (2.5 mil rows), so I need to get it done quickly.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Would the buckets limits be such that the end of previous bucket would be same as start of next one always?

Comment: @Divakar, thank you for good question. Intervals are open from the left and closed from the right `(0,3], (3,5], (5,9]` and yes limits are common.

Comment: Could there be any element in `df.A` that won't be in any bucket, i.e. outside the bucket limits?

Comment: @Divakar This is possible.

Comment: So, what would be the expected output for those ones? Add in sample with such cases?

Comment: @Divakar, I have not decided it yet, I guess assigning to end buckets would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html), with `labels=False` if you only want the index:

```
buckets = [0,3,5,9]
df['bucket'] = pd.cut(df['A'], bins=buckets)
df['bucket_idx'] = pd.cut(df['A'], bins=buckets, labels=False)
```

The resulting output:

```
   A  bucket  bucket_idx
0  1  (0, 3]           0
1  2  (0, 3]           0
2  3  (0, 3]           0
3  4  (3, 5]           1
4  6  (5, 9]           2
5  4  (3, 5]           1
6  3  (0, 3]           0
7  2  (0, 3]           0
8  7  (5, 9]           2
```

Comment: if needed, you can add `.cat.codes` to get the integer, rather than categorical dtype too

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
df['buckets_index'] = np.asarray(buckets)[:,1].searchsorted(df.A.values)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [522]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(1,8,(10000))})

In [523]: buckets = [0,3,5,9]

In [524]: %timeit pd.cut(df['A'], bins=buckets, labels=False)
1000 loops, best of 3: 460 µs per loop # @root's soln

In [525]: buckets = [(0,3),(3,5),(5,9)]

In [526]: %timeit np.asarray(buckets)[:,1].searchsorted(df.A.values)
10000 loops, best of 3: 166 µs per loop
```

**Outside limits cases :** For such cases, we need to use clipping, like so -

```
np.asarray(buckets)[:,1].searchsorted(df.A.values).clip(max=len(buckets)-1)
```

Comment: I am impressed with both yours and root's solution. I wish I can count both of your answers as correct ones. I will give answer to root, since he has lower rank. I hope you do not mind.

Comment: @user1700890 Sure, that's fine! :)